# jQuery .load() doesn't execute swiffy in loaded html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-swiffy

I have an html5 code with "swiffy" in page when i user JQuery load() function to get this page in another it doesn't appear, what is the reason ?

I user this code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URL,
        data: { }
    }).success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $('html').html(jqXHR.responseText);
        var reponse = $(jqXHR.responseText);
        var reponseScript = reponse.filter("script");
        $.each(reponseScript, function(idx, val) {
            eval(val.text); 
       });
    });
```